# RSpec test routes with mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

I have a Rails app which mounts another engine to its routes, and also overrides some routes from the engine. Here is the routes.rb:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  # some other routes
  root :to => "home#index"
end

MyNamespace::Application.routes.draw do
  class CityConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      Spree::CityZone.where(:url => request.params[:city_name]).exists?
    end
  end
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => ':city_name/', :constraints => CityConstraint.new, :as => :city
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end
```

When I try to test the routes with RSpec (2.14), I always get the following error:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "routes.rb" do
  it "test routing" do
    expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "spree/home", action: "index")
  end
end
```

> ```
>  Failure/Error: expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "home", action: "index")
>    No route matches "/"
>  # ./spec/routing/routes_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

I've found out, that when I add the following line, it works:

```
RSpec.describe "routes.rb" do
  routes { Spree::Core::Engine.routes } # this sets the routes
  it "test routing" do
    expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "spree/home", action: "index")
  end
end
```

The problem is, that I want to test the whole app, because we mount the app twice, under a city name scope (e.g. `/your_city`) and under root `/`.

When I try to set `routes { MyNamespace::Application.routes }` in my tests, I get the `No route matches "/"` error.

**Any ideas how to test the whole stack of the mounted routes, including the routes from the engine?**

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the needed routes manually:

```
RSpec.describe "routes.rb" do
  before :all do
    engine_routes = Proc.new do
      mount Spree::Core::Engine, 
            :at => ':city_name/', 
            :constraints => CityConstraint.new, 
            :as => :city
      mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
    end
    Rails.application.routes.send :eval_block, engine_routes
  end

  it "test routing" do
    expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "spree/home", action: "index")
  end
end
```

Idea taken from: http://makandracards.com/makandra/18761-rails-3-4-how-to-add-routes-for-specs-only